# How to filter the running nodes

Tags: linux, bash, kubernetes, openshift

I want to filter the running nodes list . I tried below command but its only showing running status.I need to filter with it name..Any help ?

```
[root@techsl]# kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{@.metadata.name}:{range @.status.`enter code here`conditions[*]}{@.type}={@.status};{end}{end}'| tr ';' "\n"  | grep "Ready=True"
```

Comment: Can you please show the output of the first part of the command (`kubectl ...`) with related expected output and edit it to the original question, do not put it in the comments? And prepend the output with four spaces.

Comment: sure i'll update the comment

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is easier:

```
kubectl get nodes | grep -v NotReady | awk '{print $1}' | tail -n2
server1
server3

kubectl get nodes

NAME                               STATUS     ROLES    AGE    VERSION
server1                            Ready      master   106d   v1.14.9
server2                            NotReady   <none>   106d   v1.14.9
server3                            Ready      <none>   106d   v1.14.9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{@.metadata.name}: {range @.status.conditions[4]}{@.type}; {end}{end}";
```

> kubernetes-1-17-master: Ready; kubernetes-1-17-worker: Ready;

The way you do:

```
kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{@.metadata.name}:{range @.status.conditions[4]}{@.type}={@.status}; {end}{end}" | grep "Ready=True"
```

> kubernetes-1-17-master:Ready=True; kubernetes-1-17-worker:Ready=True;

Comment: Hi @suren . if node not ready i want to get  the result to a mail . Any idea on this .  

kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{@.metadata.name}:{range @.status.conditions[4]}{@.type}={@.status}; {end}{end}" | tr ';' "\n"  | grep "Ready=True" | mail -s $subject techsl@example.com < file.txt;

Comment: honestly, for mailing I use sendgrid for while now. But should work with `mail` too.